# Assumptions about the stack before usage

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, callstack

Does the stack need to be 'cleared' before using it? In other words, before using the stack, is it safe to assume that is entirely zero'd, or that it is garbage and it can be anything? For example, let's say I move a three-byte value `AA AA AA` to `%rbp-4`:

```
 ---------------------- %rsp / %rbp

 ---------------------- -1
            AA
 ---------------------- -2
            AA
 ---------------------- -3
            AA
 ---------------------- -4
```

If I move four bytes into a register, for example:

```
movl -4(%rbp), %eax
```

Do I first need to clear the one unused bytes on the stack, or do we know for certain that the stack is already cleared?

Answer (score 3):

> ... before using the stack, is it safe to assume that is entirely zero'd ...

In nearly all use cases the stack was already "used" before you use it.

Example C code:

```
void someFunction(void)
{
    someOtherFunction();
    functionIHaveWritten();
}
```

Let's say the initial value of the stack pointer is `rsp=0x10F000`.

Now the function `someOtherFunction()` will use the stack, change the stack pointer to another value (let's say `rsp=0x10EF00`) and store some data (normally local variables) to the memory area between `0x10EF00` and `0x10F000`.

When the function `someOtherFunction()` returns, it will restore the stack pointer to `rsp=0x10F000`, but it will not clear the bytes on the stack that the function has overwritten.

Clearing would not make any sense - it would cost time and most functions do not need the stack to be cleared.

So when the function written by you - `functionIHaveWritten()` - is called, the stack contains the "garbage" written by the function `someOtherFunction()`.

> Does the stack need to be 'cleared' before using it?

If you want to ensure all bytes on the stack are zero-initialized: Yes.

However, in most cases you will not have the need for this.

Answer (score 1):

It's never safe to make any assumptions about unwritten stack space, except in `_start` in a *static* executable (otherwise the dynamic linker aka ELF interpreter could have dirtied stack space before your `_start` runs.)

Under Linux, fresh stack memory that hasn't been touched at all yet in this process will be zeroed, like other anonymous pages (the BSS, mmap(MAP_ANONYMOUS), etc.)  This avoids leaking kernel or other-user data.  It's normal to take advantage of this known state for the BSS or newly-allocated memory from mmap (e.g. that's why lazy `calloc` is cheaper for large allocations than `malloc` + `memset` - no page faults.)  But it's not normal for stack space because most functions are supposed to work regardless of whether they're reusing stack space that some earlier function used or whether they happen to be the first time touching those bytes in this process.

So basically as a dirty hack for toy programs under a known OS like Linux, especially for code-golf, sure, assume a zeroed stack.  e.g. https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/133618/extreme-fibonacci/135618#135618 assumes a zeroed stack, and that there are no signal handlers so it can use a nearly 4kiB red-zone below ESP, using `pop` to loop over an array among other dirty hacks that save space but still work in practice under known conditions on my desktop.

**Any other time (like a function you might want to call from anywhere else), no.**

How would stack memory get zeroed?  Nothing's going to waste time zeroing stack memory as functions return; usually that would be wasted time for no benefit because nothing would read those zeroes.

Most of the time, most space that gets reserved for locals and function args is written with whatever data the code wants to store there.  If that happens to be an array that needs to be zero-initialized (e.g. an array of counters), it's up to you to make that happen.

Note that even using a debugger could dirty space below the red-zone, if you do stuff like `print some_func(123)`.  GDB will use your process's stack space to call that function and get a return value.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. The memory on the stack was allocated for your program's execution, and before that was used for who knows what else. If the process that used that memory previously zeroed it, or if your operating system zeroes memory before reallocating it, then yes, you'll have zeroes in the uninitialized bytes. However, knowing nothing about your particular setup, I'd say this is extremely unlikely, and you shouldn't count on it. Those bytes almost certainly contain whatever garbage is left over from their last use.

Many modern languages do not allow programmers to read memory locations that they themselves did not initialize, to avoid undefined behavior. Even in older languages like C/C++ that don't automatically forbid this, it is *highly* encouraged that you don't assume anything about newly allocated stack/heap memory.